# Store value, check it up against new value for every iteration count

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran

I have a program that computes a new value (L2norm) for every new iteration count i. I want to check this value at iteration i against the value at iteration (i+1). And see if the difference is less then some  spesific value. How can I store the this value at iteration i (L2old) and check it up against L2norm at i+1 (L2norm)

If I set L2old=L2norm I just get zero every time. I want a nonzero value.

Part of my program:

```
module hei

use sub_solver

implicit none
contains

subroutine heis(f,T,n)

integer, intent(in) :: n
double precision, intent(in) :: f
double precision, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: T
double precision pi,re,L2norm
integer i
pi=3.14159265359

do i=1,50



call BC(n,T)

call gauss_seidel(n,T)

call L2normsolver(n,T,L2norm)

if (abs(L2old-L2norm) .LE. 0.0000001) then

    exit

end if

L2old=L2norm

end do

write(*,*)'iteration count',i

end subroutine heis
end module hei


subroutine L2normsolver(n,T,L2norm)

integer, intent(in) :: n
double precision, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: T
integer i,j
double precision errorsum,L2norm,pi,h,x,y

pi=3.14159265359
h=1/n
errorsum=0

!Sums up all the errors

do i=2,n+1
  do j=2,n+1

   x=(j-1.5)*1/n
   y=(i-1.5)*1/n

   errorsum=errorsum+(T(i,j)-(cos(pi*x)*sinh(pi*y))/sinh(pi))**2

   end do
end do

!L2 norm
L2norm=sqrt(errorsum/(n**2))


end subroutine L2normsolver
```

Comment: Use some indentation in your programs. It is hard to read and hard to tell where one block starts and where it ends.

Comment: Your `L2norm` is not defined inside subroutine `heis`. You should show code that can be actually compiled.

Comment: You should just put `L2old = L2norm` *after* the check in the if statement.

Comment: After the If statement? (see edit) It would work but, L2old dosent exist before I have calculated it in L2normsolver. So for the for the first iteration I am taking the difference between an unknown value and a knownvalue

Comment: Yes, after. Obviously at the beginning you **have to** set L2old to something. It can't be left undefined. Best to something very large.

Comment: It isn't clear to me where L2old should be this code. If it should be in subroutine L2normsolver, because of no `implicit none` statement, L2old would be a Integer and if L2norm < 0.5 it will always be set to 0.